# How can I correctly use Parse int in my code

Tags: java, parsing

Parse int is messing up my file scanning
I'm basically trying to read the first number in this txt document and use that as the number to implement within a for loop. My code runs well without including it but I want to use this to continue with this small project.

```
 {
        int i=0;
        while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            //int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
         
            if(line.toLowerCase().equals("basketball")){
                AllSports.add(new Basketball(i));
            }
            if(line.toLowerCase().equals("football")){
                AllSports.add(new Football(i));
            }
            
            for(Sports obj:AllSports){
                obj.Score_Med();
                obj.Score_Med();
            }
            i++;
        }
        }
```

I commented the parseInt line, I've also tried .nextInt and it still gives me an error. My txt file currently looks like this:

3
Basketball
Basketball
Football

and the error I'm getting is

```
File name?: 
input.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Basketball"        
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:665)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:781)
        at Sport_Runner.main(Sport_Runner.java:24)
```

My txt file:

```
3
Basketball
Basketball
Football
```

Line 24 is where the parseInt line is.

Comment: How should be *"Basketball"* looks as a number?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Names should be camelCase not snake_case, variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: You are calling `Integer.parseInt(line)` for every line in your file. Since only the first line contains a number, it will fail for all subsequent lines. You need to change your code such that `Integer.parseInt(line)` is only used for the first line in the file.

Comment: Ill include the example as an edit, and regarding the naming conventions, those variable and class names are made by my professor sadly, you're still right though.

Comment: Thomas, is it reasonable to create nested loops so that the Integer.parseInt(line) runs once and the rest loops normally?

Comment: No, I do not think that nested loops is the way to go. The idea would be not to use a while loop at all. Check if `inFile` has a line, if so read that line and parse that first line as int. Then use a for loop that reads a number of lines equal to the number parsed from the first line.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, everything inside the `whileLoop` will be running more than once; your input only has one number, so if you're calling `parseInt` on `nextLine` inside your loop, you can expect to be parsing multiple lines.

Basically, you need to be doing that outside of your loop. Also I would probably use the int as the condition of the loop (for rather than while), though assuming no sneaky input it should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You read from file  with `inFile.hasNextLine()` command. You wrote your txt file is `3 Basketball Basketball Football`. Actually this is just 1 line. You should enter new lines to your your txt file and it should be look like this :

```
3
Basketball
Basketball
Football
```

NOTE : I strongly suggest you do not leave any space for number lines.

First you will get 3, then you will get Basketball...

Also you the easiest way to parse a number among values that is not number is to  use try catch block. Because ussually you can not know which line index is number or string.